# Java is the reference of the object stored in the cache or the object himself?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, shared-memory, heap-memory

If for example I have:

```
final Myobject o = new Myobject();
```

This is stored in the heap ok.
For performances reason this is also stored in the local processor cache who is using it, my question is: Does a multi-thread suffer of visibility problem?

2 different scenario:

1) If the whole structure of the object is stored in the cache and some other thread modify it yes, this should be a visibility problem.

2) If only the reference is stored in the cache then even if another thread modify it there should not be a problem because every thread would read from the main memory/heap.

Is my reasoning right?

As next question I want know what java stores in caches, if the whole structure of the object is copied form the heap to the cache or only the reference, where can I find this information?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you talking about the CPU cache (L1, L2 etc)?

Comment: "Does a multi-thread suffer of visibility problem?" Yes.

Comment: The Java Memory Model defines what guarantees exist around accessing data from multiple threads.  If you use suitable locking constructs (etc.), then these questions are moot.

Comment: Yes, I think they are the only cache there are if I'm right

Comment: It's also worth noting that the heap and the cache are not distinct things.  The heap is an abstraction, built inside virtual memory.  That itself is an abstraction on top of physical memory, parts of which are duplicated into various caches at various times.

Answer (score 1):

The content of CPU caches is controlled by the CPU, i.e. the actual hardware. It caches arbitrary memory contents and does not distinguish between references or objects.

Therefore, visibility problems are possible whenever mutable memory is accessed by several threads.

Java guarantees that local variables in a method are only accessed by a single thread. That is, if you do

```
void someMethod() {
   final Myobject o = new Myobject();
   // do something with o
}
```

the reference will not be shared, but the object might (if the constructor stores a reference to the object where another thread might see it).

Answer (score 0):

The data with the reference value, and the data for the object, is stored in two different places in memory.

The data for the object is likely stored in multiple places in memory, e.g. if the object has a `String` field, the `String` object is itself two objects (the `String` object and the `char[]` with the text), so that means your object might be in 3 different places in memory.

With your reference to your object, that means a total of 4 different memory locations, just for a simple object with a `String` field.

Those 4 locations are **independently cached** by the CPU, as needed.

For example, if you write `o.getName().length()`, it requires the CPU to:

- Read the reference
- Read the `name` field of `Myobject` (a `String` reference)
- Read the `value` field of `String` (a `char[]` reference)
- Read the `length` of `char[]`

All 4 memory locations will be loaded into the CPU cache.

Some of the memory locations may be very close to each other and reside in the same memory block, e.g. the `String` object and the `char[]` may be next to each other, so only 3 memory loads are needed, but above operation will likely access 4 different memory blocks.

Note that it doesn't matter whether your reference is on the stack (local variable or parameter) or on the heap (field of another object), it's still just data in memory.